# Not able to animate scroll div to top of page on click

Tags: jquery

I am working on this demo. Why am I not able to animate the `#box-2` div to top on click?

```
$('#box-2').animate({scrollTop : 0},700);
```

```js
$("#box-2").on("click", function(){
  $('#box-2').animate({scrollTop : 0},700);
});
```

```css
body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; }

.box{
  height: 100vh;
}
#box-1{
 background:khaki;
}
#box-2{
 background:red;
}
#box-3{
 background:green;
}
#box-4{
 background:orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-md-12 box" id="box-1" > </div>
<div class="col-md-12 box" id="box-2" > </div>
<div class="col-md-12 box" id="box-3" > </div>
<div class="col-md-12 box" id="box-4" > </div>
```

Comment: so are you replacing the places of box1 and box2 on click ?

Comment: That's right but let say scrool box 2 to top and not replacing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fiddle code`[check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cywd5amg/)Check this fiddle

You are clicking on #box-2 and expecting ot to be on top  but it is already on top as you see it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `$('html,body')`, as described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18780639/378779

Comment: I do not want to scrool to top of page! I want to send the `box-2` to top

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.mybtn').click(function(){
   $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $('.blue').offset().top
   },'slow');
});
```

```css
.red{
   background-color:red;
   height:100vh;
   }
   
   .blue{
      background-color:blue;
      height:100vh;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='red'>
  <button class='mybtn'>Click here to scroll to blue div</button>
</div>
<div class='blue'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't initially clear what you meant by:

> animate the #box-2 div to top on click

Now that you've asked to actually *move* `#box-2` to the top of the screen (which I'll interpret to mean "physically above `#box-1`), I'll refer you to this code:

```
$("#box-2").on("click", function(){
    $('#box-2:parent').each(function () {
        $(this).insertBefore($(this).prev('#box-1'));
    });
});
```

Which was answered here: [Switch positions of 2 divs with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030322/switch-positions-of-2-divs-with-jquery)