# Swap Position of two DIV using ID

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

i'm trying to change the position of two DIV'S in jquery, it seems that i may be a little confuse because it is already swapping position, but when it do, it duplicates the field.

i tried using insertBefore and insertAfter.

```
<div id="before_stops">                                         
   <li><span><img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/multi_stops.png') ?>" width="18px"height="18px"/></span>                                             
          <div class="verticalLine"></div>                                         
            <span class="text multi_non_append_stops"></span>                                               
             <br><br>                                            
    </li>                                    
 </div>
```

```
<div id="multi_stops">                                           
   <span class="text multi">
     <li><span>
     <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/EndPoint.png')?>" width="18px" height="18px"></span>
     <div class="verticalLine"></div>
    <br/><br>
    </li>
</span>
</div>
```

Here is my javascript code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.stops.length; i++) {
  if(value == "A" || value == "B"){
                        $('#multi_stops').insertBefore($('#before_stops'));
                        $('.multi').append('<li><span><img src="' + base_url + 'assets/images/multi_stops.png" width="18px" height="18px"></span><div class="verticalLine"></div>' + data.stops[i].stopDestination + "<br/><br></li>");
}else{
                        $('#multi_stops').insertAfter($('#before_stops'));
                        $('.multi').append('<li><span><img src="' + base_url + 'assets/images/multi_stops.png" width="18px" height="18px"></span><div class="verticalLine"></div>' + data.stops[i].stopDestination + "<br/><br></li>");
                    }
                }
```

what is happening is instead of having a output of

if the value is `A` or `B`

it should be 
`<div id ="multi_stops"></div>
 <div id ="before_stops"><div>`

but what is happening to me is
`<div id ="multi_stops"></div>
 <div id ="before_stops"><div>
 <div id ="multi_stops"></div>`

else if the value is not `A` or `B`
it should only be 
`<div id ="before_stops"></div>
 <div id ="multi_stops"><div>`

but what is happening is 
`<div id ="before_stops"></div>
 <div id ="multi_stops"><div>
 <div id ="multi_stops"></div>`

it is duplicating. what am i doing wrong here.

Comment: Can you create a runable snippet that demonstrates the issue?  As it is, this could be caused by the HTML you have.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switch positions of 2 divs with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030322/switch-positions-of-2-divs-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to copy the element, insert it after, then delete the first one. Or you would end up with duplicates. You could use jquerys [detach](https://api.jquery.com/detach/) method. It removes the object but it keeps the data. Use it like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.stops.length; i++) {
    if (value == "A" || value == "B") {
        $('#multi_stops').detach().insertBefore($('#before_stops'));
        $('.multi').append('<li><span><img src="' + base_url + 'assets/images/multi_stops.png" width="18px" height="18px"></span><div class="verticalLine"></div>' + data.stops[i].stopDestination + "<br/><br></li>");
    } else {
        $('#multi_stops').detach().insertAfter($('#before_stops'));
        $('.multi').append('<li><span><img src="' + base_url + 'assets/images/multi_stops.png" width="18px" height="18px"></span><div class="verticalLine"></div>' + data.stops[i].stopDestination + "<br/><br></li>");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! this solution works! thank you very much sir!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="holder">
    <div id="before_stops"> 
    </div>
    <div id="multi_stops">  
    </div>
</div>

if(value == "A" || value == "B"){
    $("#before_stops").appendTo(".holder");
}else{
    $("#multi_stops").appendTo(".holder");
}
```

Live example: https://codepen.io/noelelias/pen/bGbwwBz

Comment: it is still duplicating :(